# FragmentPagerAdapter of ListFragments: how to load ListView selection?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-listfragment, fragmentpageradapter

I have a problem with a personal Android application that is driving me crazy.

I have an activity with a **PagerSlidingTabStrip** which is composed of a **FragmentPagerAdapter** with **4 fixed tabs**, as on the picture below.

[image]

The first tab is a sort of summary, which reports the selections items done on the following tabs (2, 3 and 4 in the image). Each of the ListFragment is instantiated on the **getItem** method of the FragmentAdapter and I run this code when each ListFragment is loaded:

```java
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Set adapter and options
    setListAdapter(mAdapter);
    getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

    // Code omitted
    // currentSelection is a field set by a method on the ListFragment

    // Load selection
    setSelectedItem(currentSelection);
}

public void setSelectedItem(int val) {  
    // Check if the ListView exists
    if (getActivity() != null) {
        // Set selection
        try {
            getListView().setItemChecked(val - 1, true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("myapp", "Exception while setting selection!");
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I'm calling a method on the ListFragment which sets the **currentSelection** integer variable to a number and when I swipe the tabs the ListFragments show the correct selected items. This works perfectly.

The problem raises when I try to update the lists on the code (i.e. updating the ListFragment adapters with new strings): I want to update the **currentSelection** too, based on values saved on my database.

This is what happens:

1. I load a selection of "2-3-5" from the database and assign the field **currentSelection** of the three ListFragment tabs to those values.
2. If I swipe to tab 2 and item number "2" is selected (see image, **correct!**)
3. On tab 3, item number "3" is selected (**correct!**)
4. On tab 4, item number "5" is selected (**correct!**)
5. I load a new set of items and a selection of "1-2-3" from the database; then I assign the field **currentSelection** of the three ListFragment tabs again.
6. On tab 4, the selection is refreshed and it's now "3" (**correct!**)
7. I swipe to tab 3 and item number "2" is selected (**correct!**)
8. I swipe to tab 2 and item number "2" is selected (**WRONG as it's the old value!**)

So on the tab number 2 (which is 2 tabs far from 4) the selection is not updated. Also, when I'm on tab 4 and update the data, the **setSelectedItem** method of tab 2 goes into the exception which is catched ("Content not yet created"). The activity exists, but the ListView seems unable to accept the selection with **setItemChecked**.

EDIT: When I move from tab 4 to 3 (step 7) **onViewCreated of tab 2** is called and if there I call **setSelectedItem** it does NOT raise exceptions, but the selection is not set too.

How can I select the item I want on all the three tabs, if **getListView()** fails?

Comment: *...goes into the exception which is catched ("Content not yet created")* - because the fragment's view gets destroyed so there's no `ListView` to work with. Because there's no view, the update doesn't happen when you are at tab 4 and as you go to tab 2 the `ListView` is automatically rebuilt with the previous state(along with the previous selection). Rethink your approach, calling setter methods on fragments used by a ViewPager to update data isn't a good idea(also, updating stuff the user doesn't currently see should be avoided).

Comment: @Luksprog Thanks, have you got any suggestions on a different approach? I'm updating the three tabs because when you swipe the selection (and the data of course) has to be there, otherwise you'll swipe an empty panel.

Comment: Expose the selection in the activity and let each fragment get the  `currentSelection` from there. When you get a selection, you'll update the fragments(I'm assuming that you call `setSelectedItem()` on each of them right now?!) but first you'll test if `getView()` is non null. If it is non null then the list is available so you'll do the update. Otherwise abort. Each of those listfragments will also have in their `onCreateView()` method some code to get the current selection from the activity(so when one of the fragments get recreated you have the selection available).

Comment: Surely I'm missing something, but isn't this what I'm already doing in the ListFragment, although moved on the activity? When the fragments are reloaded I already get the correct selection (in fact steps 1-4 are correct), the problem is when I update the data "in place" and then go to tab 2. For example, on **step "7" of my list** (i.e. when I move from tab 4 to 3) **onViewCreated of tab 2** is invoked and if there I call setSelectedItem it does NOT raise exceptions, but the selection is not set too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Also, when I'm on tab 4 and update the data, the setSelectedItem
>   method of tab 2 goes into the exception which is catched ("Content not
>   yet created").

This is happening because you're too far away from the visible page which means that the view of the fragment get destroyed(for efficiency purposes).

> How can I select the item I want on all the three tabs, if
>   getListView() fails?

Move the setSelectedItem() method in the onResume() callback of the ListFragment. Right now, you do make the right setup to restore the selected item, but, as the fragment's view is destroyed and automatically restored(using the previous selection), you'll end up with the old value as the system restore happens *after* your call in onActivityCreated(). onResume() is the last callback to execute before the fragment is completely available so you'll be sure to have the last restore of currentSelection.

Comment: Thanks! Moving **setSelectedItem** inside **onResume()** fixed the selection issue. So easy, so great.

Comment: Also, to avoid raising the exception ("Content not yet created"), I've updated the **setSelectedItem** method by replacing `if (getActivity() != null)` with `if (getActivity() != null && isResumed())`. This way it will be executed only when the ListView is created.